# Bind DataGrid to DataTable haveing columns of type Custom Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

I have DataTable and I am trying to bind DataGrid with DataTable. But my columns are not of simple type, they are of custom Objects.

```
public class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Node(string name, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }
    }

public class NodeBool
    {
        public bool Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Node(bool name, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }
    }


     <DataGrid Name="data1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" />
```

The columns are not known before execution. They are known at runtime based on a list, ad list is used to add columns in the datatable

When I bind it to datagrid, For each row under column full class name is displayed. I want to bind it to class property and depending on the property checkbox (bool) or textbox (string) should be displayed.

I am following MVVM model.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use in below mentioned code.

```
public class NodeBool
{
    public bool Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public NodeBool(bool name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

then you have to declare the ObservableCollection like

```
 private ObservableCollection<NodeBool> _MyData=new ObservableCollection<NodeBool>();

    public ObservableCollection<NodeBool> MyData
    {
        get { return _MyData; }
        set { _MyData = value; RaisePropertyChanged("MyData"); }
    }
```

and then you have to enter the value in collecton like

```
  MyData.Add(new NodeBool(true,1));
```

and your datagrid look like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn MinWidth="150" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="180" Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I need to use my Datatable. My DataTable columns are decided based on user input and can be in any number. So they should be created at runtime and not to be mentioned in XAML. What I meant is my DataTable Column is declared like this MyDataTable.Columns.Add("xyz", typeof(NodeBool)) and in that Column i want a checkbox which displays the propert NodeBool.Name

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is  Change your Code Likes this

```
 <DataGrid Name="data1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" />
```

and in Code Behind you can do is

Create a one DataTable and Add Columns in that and add Data in that

```
 DataTable dataTable=new DataTable();
```

//for loop getting all properties of object using reflection
                dataTable.Columns.Add(item.Name);

//for loop for gettting all the information in dataTable

```
DataRow  dr;
```

//add each value like this

dr=dataTable.NewRow();

dr[propertyName] = object.Propertyname;

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
   dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

//  then bind that table to datagrid.

```
   data1.ItemSource = dataTable.DefaultView
```

or

```
   data1.DataContext = dataTable;
```

Exact Code Base will look like this
Here  I assume that your source of information will be list of class of type(Node class) it will convert it to respective  dataTable and will show the datagrid

```
public void ConvertListToDataTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Node obj = new Node();
    //here obj is instance of your node type
    foreach (var item in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(item.Name);
    }

    List<Node> objDetails = new List<Node>();
    Node objNode = new Node();
    objNode.Name = true;
    objNode.Id = "Test B";

    Node objNode1 = new Node();
    objNode1.Name = false;
    objNode1.Id = "Test B 1";

    objDetails.Add(objNode);
    objDetails.Add(objNode1);

    DataRow dr;
    for (int i = 0; i < objDetails.Count; i++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (var item in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            dr[item.Name] = objDetails[i].GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(objDetails[i], null);
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    dt.AcceptChanges();
    data1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: In this method, I am adding the property as element in the row. I need to add Object as a whole, so that when I fetch it from Datatable i should be able to get the Id property also.

Comment: I had Added New exact Code that will might help you and it has used reflection so in future  any numbers of properties is added to the Node Class it will handle automatically and will be shown on Front end no manual coding you need to do for that.